# $.ajax giving error 503 when $.post is ok - django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Is there any difference between `$.post()` and `$.ajax()`? I'm asking that because I read that `$.post()` is a shorthand notation for `$.ajax()`, however my code isn't working with `$.ajax()`. I keep getting a 503 error code that doesn't appear when using `$.post()`.

These are my implementations:

```
  function botao_curtir_clicado(id) {
      var URL = '/curtir_post/'
      var parametros = {
            post_id : id,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken : "{{csrf_token}}",
      }
      $.post(URL, parametros, function (data){
            trocar_estado(id, data);
      })
  }
```

and

```
function botao_curtir_clicado(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/curtir_post/',
        type: 'POST',
        csrfmiddlewaretoken : "{{csrf_token}}",
        post_id : id,

        success: function(data) {
            trocar_estado(id, data)
        },

        error: function(data) {
            console.log("Aconteceu algum erro ao curitr um post")
        }
    })
}
```

I know it's probably a silly bug, but I can't find it! Thanks

[Update]: Changing `post_id : id,` to `data : { post_id : id },` doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: ajax could be get or post. So post is a specialized ajax.
Your parameters in ajax call seem to be problematic.
I would put them in the data structure as below:

```
data : { csrfmiddlewaretoken : "{{csrf_token}}", post_id : id }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending the data

```
function botao_curtir_clicado(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/curtir_post/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {//sent data using the dat key
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
            post_id: id,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            trocar_estado(id, data)
        },

        error: function (data) {
            console.log("Aconteceu algum erro ao curitr um post")
        }
    })
}
```